# 504 Gateway Issue with MERN App on Amazon AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mern

I have a simple MERN stack web app that runs fine locally. Its essentially a search app like Google which takes input from user and returns results. The app only does read operation and nothing else (no create/update/delete).

Locally I run it in two ports and it works fine. I am using the free shared MongoDB cloud server.

In production, I am running in Amazon EC2. To set up everything: I followed this post: https://dev.to/rmiyazaki6499/deploying-a-production-ready-react-express-app-on-aws-62m

I am using the free tier AWS. So I did not do Elastic IP and SSL part of the setup.
Nginx handles the routing. Following is the Nginx config setup.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name _;
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        client_body_buffer_size 16k;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
# node api reverse proxy // the /api/ is assuming your api routes start with that 
 i.e. www.your-site.com/api/endpoint
 location /api/ {
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

I used pm2 to start both frontend and api. The app runs fine but will eventually give me 504 Gateway error. Being new to AWS, I am not sure which log to look at to pin point the issue. So far I cannot find anything in Nginx logs and pm2 logs causing the issue. I normally run into the gateway issue when the query takes sometime to process and send the response.

After some googling, one of the suggestion was to increase the NGINX timeout . So I created /etc/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf

```
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
send_timeout 600;
```

Today to test the app wont run into same thing, I had about 6 users concurrently used the app and it ran into same issue. I am not sure what else to do ? which log to look at? how to pinpoint the issue and fix it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get the gateway error? In the browser or inside the EC2? If you curl your nginx from the inside of the EC2, what do you see?

Comment: @AllanChua In the browser. Now I see the gateway error, I cannot ssh into the EC2 instance(it also hangs as well). I will have to restart the EC2 and redeploy.

Comment: Please let me know if it works well!

Comment: what do you mean to by curl your nginx?

Answer (score 0):

[Gateway Error 504](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504) is generally thrown back by a gateway to indicate that the upstream server could not be reached.

Since you are hosting your EC2 instance:

- Check if your client's IP address is whitelisted in the security group.
- If you are using a load balancer, check if the client's IP address is whitelisted in the load balancer's security group
- Check if there are NACLs in the host VPC preventing the connectivity
- Check if the EC2 machine, the app inside and/or its dependencies are alive

Comment: I am not using a load balancer or a private network. When the gateway error occurs, I cannot ssh to the EC2. So I assume the app is dead. To allow inbound traffic, I have configured ports client and API port to be accessible by anyone via TCP connection (0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: `curl localhost:80`

Comment: I just restarted the server and have not started client or api yet. When I run the above command, it returns html code with 502 Bad Gateway at the moment

Comment: once I start the client and api, i get bunch of html code "This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty pa"

Comment: This means that the app is dead when the 504 gateway occurs @Sohil, this is application layer issue that we can't debug.